# .NET threading: how can I capture an abort on an unstarted thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-abort

edit: this seems to be a sticking point, so I'll just get it out of the way:

I'm not using this for synchronization.  Simply to kill long-running tasks when they no longer become necessary / desirable.
**Hypothetically**: assume these threads simply write to the console (say: "Thread 1"), sleep a random length, and then exit.  If they're aborted, I want them to inform me with another console write (say: "Thread 1 aborted").  And I wish to be able to jump *straight* to the abort code if I try to abort it prior to it being run, without any chance of it performing its normal functions.  If it's aborted during normal functioning, it will of course print both.

---

I have a chunk of threads I wish to run in order, on an ASP site running .NET 2.0 with Visual Studio 2008 (no idea how much all that matters, but there it is), and they may have aborted-clean-up code which should be run regardless of how far through their task they are.  So I make a thread like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(delegate() {
   try { 
      /* do things */ 
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("try");
   }
   catch (ThreadAbortException) {
      /* cleanup */ 
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("catch");
   }
});
```

Now, if I wish to abort the set of threads part way through, the cleanup may still be desirable later on down the line.  Looking through MSDN implies you can .Abort() a thread that has not started, and then .Start() it, at which point it will receive the exception and perform normally.  Or you can .Join() the aborted thread to wait for it to finish aborting.  Presumably you can combine them.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta(v=VS.80).aspx
>   To wait until a thread has aborted, you can call the Join method on the thread after calling the Abort method, but there is no guarantee the wait will end.
>   If Abort is called on a thread that has not been started, the thread will abort when Start is called. If Abort is called on a thread that is blocked or is sleeping, the thread is interrupted and then aborted.

Now, when I debug and step through this code:

```
t.Abort(); // ThreadState == Unstarted | AbortRequested
t.Start(); // throws ThreadStartException: "Thread failed to start."
// so I comment it out, and
t.Join(); // throws ThreadStateException: "Thread has not been started."
```

At no point do I see any output, nor do any breakpoints on either the try or catch block get reached.
Oddly, ThreadStartException is not listed as a possible throw of .Start(), from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d(v=VS.80).aspx  (or any other version)

I understand this could be avoided by having a start parameter, which states if the thread should jump to cleanup code, and foregoing the Abort call (which is probably what I'll do).  And I *could* .Start() the thread, and then .Abort() it.  But as an indeterminate amount of time may pass between .Start and .Abort, I'm considering it unreliable, and the documentation seems to say my original method should work.

Am I missing something?  Is the documentation wrong?

edit: ow.  And you can't call .Start(param) on a non-parameterized Thread(Start).  Is there a way to find out if a thread is parameterized or not, aside from trial and error?  I see a private m_Delegate, but nothing public...

Comment: I'd guess you're not catching the exception (a) because it is not thrown while executing code in the `try…catch` (b) because it is a `ThreadStartException` while you are catching a `ThreadAbortException`.

Comment: try more generic catch (Exception), put a break point in there and see what kinds of exceptions you get, code around that.  BTW Microsoft documentation can be and is sometimes wrong :)

Comment: @Jay: Yes, but the documentation literally *says* a ThreadAbortException will be created only if you .Start after .Abort.  And it's how all example code looks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception(v=VS.80).aspx (though granted, those are started first).

Comment: @David: Just tried; no exceptions caught in the thread.  Wrapping .Start/.Join results in an InnerException of ThreadAbortException, but it still doesn't call the thread's exception handler.

Comment: Is there an `InnerException` in that `ThreadStartException`?

Comment: @Jay: There's an inner ThreadStartException, but it's external to the thread.  Finally is never reached.

Comment: One more reason not (never) to use Thread.Abort()

Comment: @Henk: no kidding.  Know another way to stop threads on command, though?

Comment: I added this as a common mistake for developers to avoid a while back (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380819/common-programming-mistakes-for-net-developers-to-avoid/1863735#1863735).  Calling Abort just causes more headaches then its worth.  Using a Mutex or some other locking mechanism like the link Preli posted is the best way to go.

Comment: @groxx: mayb you should read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/22/should-i-specify-a-timeout.aspx

Comment: @SwDevMan81: added a comment on that answer: Calling Thread.ResetAbort(); will stop the Abort exception from continuing.  As to the mutex / locking: I'm not using this for synchronization.  Simply for killing long-running tasks when they no-longer become useful.

Comment: If you can, may want to look into using Tasks instead of managing the threads yourself.

Comment: @David: interesting, hadn't heard of those before.  Unfortunately, I can't; this will be used in both a .NET 3.5 and an ASP .NET 2.0 projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using ...

```
t.Abort();
t.Start();
```

... the innerException of the ThreadStartExcpetion will contain the ThreadAbortExeption just as msdn states: (*if Abort is called on a thread that has not been started, the thread will abort when Start is called*)

If you execute ...

```
t.Start();
t.Abort();
```

... the ThreadAbortException may never occure because the thread had no time to start before it was aborted.

If you test something like ...

```
t.Start();
Thread.Sleep(100);
t.Abort();
```

... the "cleanup" code should always be executed.

If you need to execute cleanup-code even if the Thread has not started to do anything a possible solution would to start a cleanup method together with the Abort call.

Moreover you should try to avoid aborting threads and use different techniques (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964.aspx)

Comment: That explains it pretty well.  It does make .Abort a rather indeterminate thing, though :\ nuttery.  And sleeping isn't really an option; it'll allow partial-execution of an "aborted" thread.  I'll just require anything which needs guaranteed-cleanup to take a parameter to denote if it's "aborted" or not, and they can throw and catch their own Abort to cause the same behavior.  And I'm not using this for synchronization, just for potentially-too-long-running tasks that aren't 100% required to finish.  Abort seems to be the only way to stop such an operation.

Comment: You could use something like this to check if the thread is running at all and to wait until the Thread really is aborted:
if (t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running || t.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
            {
                t.Abort();
                while (t.ThreadState == ThreadState.AbortRequested)
                {
                    //wait a little bit
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Thread killed");
            }

Comment: As long as the thread was started, you can .Abort() and .Join(); .Join() will wait for the Abort to finish (though that *could* be forever, and Aborts can be refused anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I realize what the documentation implied to you, but that is not what happens.  If you abort a thread and then start it, it will never execute in any way.  The CLR is smart enough to know that thread-aborts are a precarious business, and an opportunity to skip the execution of the thread altogether is therefore not to be missed.

Perhaps make your cleanup code into a subroutine.  If the parent thread aborts or knows about the abort, it calls the cleanup code explicitly.

Keep in mind that .net's notion of "cleaning up" after aborting a thread, is to unload the appdomain of the assemblies that were executing the aborted thread.  It is another way of saying "don't expect this to clean up well."  You should first always seek a design that does not require aborting threads.